# Difference between Cary-Blair and Amies transport media for Staphylococcus and Streptococcus?

Tags: microbiology

I normally use Amies medium, but I today heard that Cary-Blair is also possible.

**When should you use Cary-Blair medium?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](http://www.copanusa.com/products/history_of_transport/) (no connection) states (my emphasis):

> Unlike **Cary-Blair Medium, which is almost exclusively associated with enteric transport**, both Stuart and Amies Medium have been widely used for the transportation of a diverse range of clinical swab samples from sites including the eye, ear, nose, throat, skin, genital tract and wounds.

Comment: This is very general. I am interested if there is any advantage of using the other in some circumstances. I think if you use Amies transport medium, you do not need to use Cary-Blair transport medium in most of the cases.

Comment: I put this up because it clearly states that Cary-Blair medium is used for enteric samples. Whether you **should** use it for that purpose is not explained. Presumably the Staphylococcus and Streptococcus you refer to are not samples of that type, so you would use Amies.